# LC-3 How to tell if data in register is a valid 7-bit ASCII code?

Tags: assembly, ascii, lc3

I am studying for a final that will include LC3 programming. one of the sample questions requires me to be able to write a piece of assembly code to do different things depending on if the value of a register is or is not a valid ascii code. What's a way to tell if a value is  a valid 7 bit ascii code or not?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Test to see if the high bit is set ?

Comment: define "valid 7-bit ASCII code" and then check for that, range checks if not all 7 bit patterns are "valid" or just look for the msb if that is the only thing that would determine valid vs invalid

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII character set has 128 characters. It has one encoding: one byte per character with the code-unit value equal to the codepoint number. Therefore integers representable in 7 bits are valid.

So, clear the 7 low-order bits and test the entire register for 0. To clear bits in a register, you might need to AND by NOT 0x7F.

Comment: Or you can just test the 8 bit value to see whether it's negative (i.e. sign bit set). LC-3 apparently has a conditional branch instruction which tests the sign bit, so this would seem to be the simplest/most obvious way to go.

Comment: Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708532/why-isnt-my-assembly-program-setting-r1-to-the-correct-value